# change fancybox design - add another div without window shaking

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have JW player on Fancybox window. Everything works well, now I have only one design problem:

When player window is shown (when it fires), it moves "bottom to up", from down up to the window. It is because I added another div under the player. how can i fix this?
Here is a demo example: http://teodore.ge/test/demo/

I have made that  like that:

```
<script>

      $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        fitToView: false, // to show videos in their own size
        content: '<div></div>', // create temp content
        scrolling: 'no', // don't show scrolling bars in fancybox
        afterLoad: function () {

          // get dimensions from data attributes
          var $width = $(this.element).data('width'); 
          var $height = $(this.element).data('height');


          var link=$(this.element).context.attributes.yutubelink.nodeValue;

          this.content = ' <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  src="player.swf" width="640" height="383"    style="undefined"  allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="file='+link+'&amp;skin=nacht.zip&amp;autostart=true">'; 
        },
        afterShow: function(){
          var toolbar = "<div id='tools'>" + $("#appendContent div").eq(this.index).html() + "</div>";
           $(".fancybox-outer").append(toolbar);
          }
      });   

</script>


<div id="appendContent" style="display: none;  width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div > 1111   That div  is the problem <br><br><br>  1111111 <br> <br> </div>
    <div> 2222:  That div  is the problem  <br><br><br> 2222222 <br> <br> </div>
</div>



    <a class="fancybox"  yutubeLink="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3iYnHx8P0s" > 
    <img src=" 1.jpg"  width="360" height="240"></a><br>

    <a class="fancybox"  yutubeLink="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USgLNBsnRGo"> 
    <img src=" 2.jpg" width="360" height="240"></a> <br>
```

Comment: page works well. please check again :-)

Comment: dear tazo, demo page have password :)

Answer (score 0):

I move the function which was adding a new div beside the player. I move the function from afterShow() to  afterLoad() function. Adding div after loading  caused that problem (it changes location of div). because player must be at the center of the screen and when I was adding a new div, that position was changing.